# req.body.object is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The req.body.object keeps returning an undefined value.

I have body parser imported yet it still is undefined when I to console.log()

```js
//javascript
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/demos/net', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.object)
  res.render('demos/demos.ejs')
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
});
```

```html
<form class="form" action="/demos/net" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" id="net-start" class="btn btn-success ">Go</button>
</form>
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="100" name="object">
```

req.body.object is being logged as undefined

Comment: The `<input>` with that name is not inside the `<form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input element is outside form. You have to move it inside form or associate it with form via `form` attribute: `form="insert-id-of-form"`

```
<input type="number" form="insert-id-of-form" class="form-control" placeholder="100"name="object">
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How and where would I do that

Comment: You can't set headers on a default form submit and using `urlencoded` is the proper way to manage default forms

Comment: You sir are a saint. I love you